# Duas ações no mesmo botão

Tags: php, html

Galera, preciso de ajuda com uma coisa simples, mas eu não consegui achar na internet, talvez por que eu não saiba o termo correto para pesquisar. Mas eu queria o seguinte: Ao clicar no botão do código abaixo, no primeiro clique vai abrir um link, e no segundo clique vai abrir o segundo link. Resumindo, dois links no mesmo botão. 
Atualmente meu botão é assim, mas queria fazer ele abrir outro link antes de abrir o link do www.google.com. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

```
<div class="baixar">
    <a id="botao2" href="www.google.com" target="_blank"><h3>DOWNLOAD</h3> </a>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode alterar o `href` do link após o primeiro clique, tudo dentro do atributo `onclick`:

```
<a id="botao2" href="http://primeirolink.com" target="_blank"
onclick="var t=this; setTimeout(function(){t.href='http://www.google.com'},10)">
   <h3>DOWNLOAD</h3>
</a>
```

Ao clicar no link irá abrir a URL `http://primeirolink.com` e o atributo `href` irá mudar para `http://www.google.com`. Ao clicar novamente irá abrir `http://www.google.com`.

O `setTimeout` é para dar um pequeno delay para que o atributo seja alterado somente após o click.

Comment: Cara, eu tô tentando assim

`<a id="botao2" href="http://primeirolink.com" target="_blank" onclick="var t=this; setTimeout(function(){t.href="<?php echo base64_decode($queryString["src"])?>"},10)> <h3>DOWNLOAD</h3> </a> `


Mas não ta mudando o link, fica sempre indo para o primeiro link.

Comment: Olhe no código-fonte da página para ver como está ficando o HTML do link.

Comment: Faltou fechar o onclick com `"` após o `,10)`.

Comment: Eu coloquei: http://prntscr.com/oll273 Mas continua sem funcionar :/

Comment: É após o `,10)`, assim: `<a id="botao2" href="http://primeirolink.com" target="_blank" onclick="var t=this; setTimeout(function(){t.href='<?php echo base64_decode($queryString["src"])?>'},10)"> <h3>DOWNLOAD</h3> </a>`

Comment: E o link deve ficar dentro de aspas simples. Vc colocou o código PHP dentro de aspas duplas, diferentemente do que coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Ah, agora deu certo. Muito obrigado, cara. Você é fera!

Answer (score -2):

Legal essa pergunta!
tipo ai clica no botão pela primeira vez vamos dizer que ele abra o github e  a segunda vez o stack

vamos lá

- php

```
$link_count = 0
function AlternaLinks(){
    if ($link_count == 0){
        // manda para o primeiro link
        $link_count = 1
    } else {
        // manda para o segundo link
        $link_count == 0
   }
}
```

Assim vai fica abri ao clica  o primeiro link
e ao clica novamente vai abri o segundo e assim infinitamente

### Espero ter ajudado